# export a JOGL applet and embedd into a html page

Tags: java, jar, applet, export, jogl

It is some time that I'm testing `opengl` with java and `JOGL`. I have a good result and I wan to publish it on the web, but I have a problem. I'm in eclipse, and I'm testing an Applet with `JOGL`.

EDIT: Thanks to Ricket answer it fixed this problem

<del>first of all i have this run time error (but the program works correctly):</del>

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
 adding a window to a container  at

EDIT: but it still doesn't work:

then I found this incredibly clear [page](https://jogl-demos.dev.java.net/applettest.html)
and I did what is said. I open html with the browser, the libs are downloaded, but it stops at `Starting applet AppletHelloWorld`, as that is the name I gave to my applet.

Maybe I am missing something like a main function or exporting the jar properly?

This is my main code:

```
public class AppletHelloWorld extends Applet 
{


public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 JFrame fr=new JFrame(); 
 fr.setBounds(0,0,1015,600);
 fr.add(new AppletHelloWorld());

 fr.setVisible(true);
 }
  public void init() 
 { 
  setLayout(null); 
  MyJOGLProject canvas = new MyJOGLProject(); //MyJOGLProject extends JFrame
  canvas.run(); // this do setVisible(true)
 } //....
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as the error says, you're trying to add a window to a container. A JFrame is a window. You can't add a JFrame to anything, including a Container. I think perhaps you either don't know what a JFrame is, or don't know what a Container is.

Ideally you would have MyJOGLProject extend GLEventListener instead. Then your init function would make a new GLCanvas, add an instance of MyJOGLProject to it (via addGLEventListener), and then add the GLCanvas to your applet.

Alternatively, if you're okay with the applet popping up a JFrame, then simplify your init method:

```
public void init() {
    setLayout(null);
    MyJOGLProject canvas = new MyJOGLProject();
    canvas.setVisible(true);
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: ok, now no more runtime exception but it still don't work in the browser. it stops in "Starting applet AppletHelloWorld". what else could it be?

Answer (score 2):

Use JApplet. I think that's the reason why it fails.
(Use Webstart with JNLP in NetBeans)